# How to create a unique Id for a container element?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

The problem I have is this;
I am using an editor template as follows;

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<SHP.WebUI.Models.OtherTeam>" %>

<fieldset>
    <legend><%:Model.Approver.GetName() %> team.</legend>
    <table class="groupBorder">
    <tr>
        <th align="right">Name</th>
        <th><div>Entitlement</div><div>THIS Year</div></th>
        <th><div>Days Left</div><div> THIS Year</div></th>
        <th><div>Leave</div><div>Taken</div></th>
        <th><div>Future</div><div>Booked</div><div>Leave</div></th>
        <th><div>Days Left</div><div> NEXT Year</div></th>
        <th align="center"><div style="padding-bottom:5px;">Select</div><div style="padding-left:11px;">
        <input type="checkbox" id="OtherSelectAll" /></div></th>
    </tr>
    <tbody  id="OtherSelectContainer">
    <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.TeamMembers) %>
    </tbody>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="right">Date From</td>
        <td colspan="6"><%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.CalendarVM.Dates.DateFrom) %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="right">Date To</td>
        <td colspan="6"><%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.CalendarVM.Dates.DateTo)%>OR last holiday date <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.CalendarVM.Dates.LastHolidayDateFlag)%></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
        <td colspan="6" align="left"><input type="submit" value="Submit" id="btnSubmit"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</fieldset>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $('#OtherSelectAll').change(function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('#OtherSelectContainer').find('input:checkbox').attr('checked', true);
        }
        else {
            $('#OtherSelectContainer').find('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
        }
    }); 
</script>
```

The first time it is output it works fine. However the IDs clash after that, so the Select All checkbox no longer works.
I need the ID of the tbody element to be unique, and at the same time the jquery that implements the Select All functionality needs to know what the ID is.
So how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS class names instead for your jQuery operations.

Comment: However the class names will also need to be unique, because the script needs to reference the correct container for the Select checkboxes. So how do I do that?

Comment: One of the "benefits" of .net is that it wants to own all of the element IDs so it can control everything itself. It doesn't play well. Claiming the class names for yourself is OK, even if they have to be unique, or not.